# My Nested Selection doesnt properly work. Python

Tags: python

I'm making a program and I have defined the "check password" section but for some reason I try the "check password" option and the nested selection only works to a certain point. This is the section of the code that doesn't work properly:

```
Uppercase = set("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
  Lowercase = set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
  Digits = set("0123456789")
  AllowedSymbols = set("!$%^&*()-_=+")

  if any ((c in Uppercase)for c in UserPassword):
    print ("You have used at least one uppercase letter. 5 points have been awarded.")
    TotalScore = TotalScore + 5
    if any ((c in Lowercase)for c in UserPassword):
      print ("You have used at least one lowercase letter. 5 points have been awarded.")
      TotalScore = TotalScore + 5
      if any ((c in Digits)for c in UserPassword):
        print ("You hve used at least one digit. 5 points have been awarded.")
        TotalScore = TotalScore + 5
        if any ((c in AllowedSymbols)for c in UserPassword):
          print ("You have used at least one of the allowed symbols. 5 points have been awarded.")
          TotalScore = TotalScore + 5
          if any ((c in Uppercase)for c in UserPassword) and any ((c in Lowercase)for c in UserPassword) and ((c in Digits)for c in UserPassword) and ((c in AllowedSymbols)for c in UserPassword): 
            print ("You have used at least one of all the allowed characters. 10 point have been awarded")
            TotalScore = TotalScore + 10
  else:
    print (" You haven't used any of the allowed characters so no points have been awarded.")

  print ("The score for your password so far is",TotalScore)
```

Can someone please show me where I have gone wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the traceback you are getting when it hits the error?

Answer (score 0):

I had to rework your code a little bit because there were indentation errors and there were elements missing to recreate your problem.  It is always better to include everything that we need to recreate what you are seeing. This code will run without errors (Python 2.7).

```
TotalScore = 0
UserPassword = raw_input("> ")

Uppercase = set("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
Lowercase = set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
Digits = set("0123456789")
AllowedSymbols = set("!$%^&*()-_=+")

if any ((c in Uppercase)for c in UserPassword):
    print ("You have used at least one uppercase letter. 5 points have been awarded.")
    TotalScore = TotalScore + 5
    if any ((c in Lowercase)for c in UserPassword):
        print ("You have used at least one lowercase letter. 5 points have been awarded.")
        TotalScore = TotalScore + 5
        if any ((c in Digits)for c in UserPassword):
            print ("You hve used at least one digit. 5 points have been awarded.")
            TotalScore = TotalScore + 5
            if any ((c in AllowedSymbols)for c in UserPassword):
                print ("You have used at least one of the allowed symbols. 5 points have been awarded.")
                TotalScore = TotalScore + 5
                if any ((c in Uppercase)for c in UserPassword) and any ((c in Lowercase)for c in UserPassword) and ((c in Digits)for c in UserPassword) and ((c in AllowedSymbols)for c in UserPassword): 
                    print ("You have used at least one of all the allowed characters. 10 point have been awarded")
                    TotalScore = TotalScore + 10
else:
    print (" You haven't used any of the allowed characters so no points have been awarded.")

print ("The score for your password so far is",TotalScore)
```

Output:

```
>Aa0$
You have used at least one uppercase letter. 5 points have been awarded.
You have used at least one lowercase letter. 5 points have been awarded.
You hve used at least one digit. 5 points have been awarded.
You have used at least one of the allowed symbols. 5 points have been awarded.
You have used at least one of all the allowed characters. 10 point have been awarded
('The score for your password so far is', 30)
```

However, based on the way that you've constructed your code, if a user inputs only 'a', your script returns this: `You haven't used any of the allowed characters so no points have been awarded. ('The score for your password so far is', 0)` which isn't a valid return since 'a' is an allowable character.  Take a look at your logic and indentation to see if you can get any valid input to be awarded points

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to be using nested if statements at all? The way this code currently works, you are only checking for lowercase digits if the password ALSO has uppercase digits. This seems contrary to your logic, if I understand what you're trying to do here. You currently have,

```
if (password satisfies some condition) add points,
   if (password ALSO satisfies some other condition) add points
```

What it seems like you want is,

```
if (password satisfies some condition) add points
if (password satisfies some other condition) add points
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also improve this by using set operations.  Here is a fixed version of your code that does this:

```
import string

TotalScore = 0
passwd = set(UserPassword) # create set from UserPassword
Uppercase = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
Lowercase = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
Digits = set(string.digits)
AllowedSymbols = set("!$%^&*()-_=+")

if passwd.intersection(Uppercase):
    print ("You have used at least one uppercase letter. 5 points have been awarded.")
    TotalScore += 5
if passwd.intersection(Lowercase):
    print ("You have used at least one lowercase letter. 5 points have been awarded.")
    TotalScore += 5
if passwd.intersection(Digits):
    print ("You have used at least one digit. 5 points have been awarded.")
    TotalScore += 5
if passwd.intersection(AllowedSymbols):
    print ("You have used at least one of the allowed symbols. 5 points have been awarded.")
    TotalScore += 5
if passwd.intersection(Uppercase.union(Lowercase, Digits, AllowedSymbols)):
    print ("You have used at least one of all the allowed characters. 10 point have been awarded")
    TotalScore += 10
else:
    print ("You haven't used any of the allowed characters so no points have been awarded.")

print ("The score for your password so far is", TotalScore)
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I tried your version and the returned result is not the one I'm looking for, I think there is still an error, would you mind helping?? @gammazero

Comment: Made small change to use else at end of checks.  Does that give you what you are looking for?

Comment: when I use uppercase, it works but when I use lowercase it doesn't, it says that I haven't used any of the allowed characters and the totalscore needs to have a default value of the length of the users password

Comment: @MohammedAwais The `if` statements are not nested, they are all at the same level.  It seems to do what I think you want.